# Quantity of same value in column

Tags: r

I have a data frame with 5000 lines and 9 columns. The 3rd column expresses weekday as a number (1-7, where 1 = Monday, 2 = Tuesday, 3 = Wednesday, and so on). How can I find quantity of Mondays in my table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data frame is called `d` then try `sum(d[, 3] == 1)`. If you are interested in more days of the week than just Monday, you may find `table(d[, 3])` helpful as well.

Answer (score 0):

There are three main options for counting things in R.  Since you didn't provide data, here's an example with the `Plant` column of the built-in `CO2` dataset.

```
table(CO2$Plant)    
## Qn1 Qn2 Qn3 Qc1 Qc3 Qc2 Mn3 Mn2 Mn1 Mc2 Mc3 Mc1 
##   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7

xtabs(~ Plant, CO2)
## Plant
## Qn1 Qn2 Qn3 Qc1 Qc3 Qc2 Mn3 Mn2 Mn1 Mc2 Mc3 Mc1 
##   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7   7

library(plyr)
count(CO2, "Plant")
##    Plant freq
## 1    Qn1    7
## 2    Qn2    7
## 3    Qn3    7
## 4    Qc1    7
## 5    Qc3    7
## 6    Qc2    7
## 7    Mn3    7
## 8    Mn2    7
## 9    Mn1    7
## 10   Mc2    7
## 11   Mc3    7
## 12   Mc1    7
```

Which one of these functions you want to use depends on the input and output format that you prefer.  Since `count` returns a data frame, it will probably be the one you use most often.